# Safe variable string for variable sqlite column (python)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have two questions.

I understand that something like c.execute("INSERT INTO ? VALUES ...") is a big no no, since the ? is reserved for queries, not column names that could include anything from foreign or corrupt characters, injection to anything else. So here are my questions -

1. Would the above example be safe if I could guarantee that the ? only contains real letters or real numbers from 0-9?
2. if the answer to 1 is yes, then can I do this somehow by taking any user-given string, and rejecting it if it contains anything besides alphanumeric characters (0-9, a-z)? How would I do that?

eg:

```
str="some potentially corrupt string from the user"

If (not_alphanumeric(str)):
   pass
else: 
   c.execute("INSERT INTO ? VALUES ...", (str,))
```

So in essence, if the answer to 1 is "yes", then how would I code not_alphanumeric for the conditionl test?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use parameters for table/column names, regardless of what their contents are.

The safest way to insert a user-specified table name is to check that it is in a list of known valid names:

```
valid_tables = ["ThisTable", "ThatTable"]
if str not in valid_tables:
    raise Exception("invalid table name")
```

If you do not have such a known list, [correctly quote](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) the table name as an identifer; this only requires doubling any quote character inside:

```
def sql_quote_identifier(x):
    return '"' + x.replace('"', '""') + '"'

c.execute("INSERT INTO {} VALUES ...".format(sql_quote_identifier(str)), ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer 1 but can answer 2.

To test if a sting is alphanumeric directly, do this:

```
if not str.isalnum(your_string):
       # your c.execute command 
else:  # not necessary
    pass
```

Comment: That's what I was after, thanks! Now just to find out about Q1.